# In my C# form app my chart area width is changing, when the y scale values are changing (amaount of digits). How can I keep the chart area width fix?

Tags: c#, charts, scale

In my C# form app I have a chart control. As in several measuring steps the Y scale is changing, I have programmed the scale values accordingly. But I have a problem:
My chart area (I mean the plot area without the scales) width is changing, when the y scale values are changing (amount of digits). I think the chart control keeps the chart area including the scale values fix, and therefore reducing the plotting area width when the scale value has more digits.
How can I keep the plotting area's width fix in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for my question :
I have defined the "InnerPlotPosition" of the chart area instead of the "Position"
In this case the inner plot area width stays always on the set % value.

```
        ChartArea CA = chart.ChartAreas[0];
        //CA.Position = new ElementPosition(0, 0, 100, 100);
        CA.InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(3, 0, 94, 95);
```